# Chaining queries with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, cursor, pymongo

So, I'm currently trying to make an extensible wrapper for pymongo and I found myself wishing that it was possible to query a cursor. This is mostly for making the api as clean as possible. Basically what I was imagining was something along these lines:

```
def get_all_x_type(collection):
    return collection.find({"type":"x"})

def get_all_y_kind(collection):
    return collection.find({"kind": "y"})

def get_all_x_and_y(collection):
    return get_all_x(get_all_y(collection))
```

Implementation details are actually nicer than that, but that's the general functionality I'm looking for. I know it's possible to just extend the find query, but I would like to be able to deal with cursors passed to me from other people. Is there any way to do something like this? I could checks on the cursor as I iterate through it, but that seems pretty gross and I was looking for something a bit cleaner.

Alternately is this a silly idea for some reason? I'm not a mongo expert by any means, but this functionality seemed useful to me, but it might just be my naivete.

Comment: This becomes much cleaner to implement if you use an ORM like `mongoengine`. In that world you can pass around `mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet` instances and chain calls on the `filter` method. If not, you will have to play with your `pymongo.cursor.Cursor` `explain` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chain two Pymongo Cursors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929955/chain-two-pymongo-cursors)