# Chain two Pymongo Cursors

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to chain together two Pymongo Cursors? They seem similar enough to generators that I imagined it might be possible to just use use itertools to chain them, but that sadly didn't work. Additionally I tried using the union option present for other returns, but that isn't present for cursor objects.

When I call `dir` on the cursor object the most promising thing I see is add_option, but that seems to be targeted at something different.

It would be possible to implement something like this by just adding every mongo object to a list and iterating through that, but that seems like a poor choice for a large number of reasons, so I'm wondering if there's some built in function for this or a more elegant hack for it. Any thoughts?

General not working code:

```
        prod_cursor = self.prod_index.find_modules_by_category("fakeqwerty")  # empty generators
        edge_cursor = self.edge_index.find_modules_by_category("fakeqwerty")
        for k, v in kwargs["queries"].items():
            prod_function = getattr(self.prod_index, k)
            itertools.chain(prod_cursor, prod_function(*v))
            edge_function = getattr(self.edge_index, k)
            itertools.chain(edge_cursor, edge_function(*v))
```

Where the results of edge and prod function are both cursors.

Update:

For clarity I would like the result to remain a cursor rather than be cast to some less feature-rich type as I use functions such as count elsewhere in my codebase.

Comment: `itertools.chain` certainly *should* work. What "didn't work" when you tried it, and what code did you use?

Comment: @kindall using itertools.chain casted it to a generator, which resulted in the Cursor losing a number of methods that cursor has such as count that I needed for things elsewhere in my application.

Comment: `itertools.chain` is for iterating over a chain of iterables; it doesn't have much other use and you'd usually use it directly in a 'for' statement. But it would be pretty easy to create your own class to do this. Might make a nice patch to submit to the project, in fact.

Comment: @kindall Good suggestion. I might actually start hacking on that, though I was ideally looking for more of a quick fix on this one, it might be better to just bit the bullet on this one for future generations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this code works:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> mc = MongoClient()
>>> db = mc["test_db"]
>>> col = db["test_collection"]

>>> col.insert({"aaaa":1})
>>> col.insert({"bbbb":2})

>>> cur1 = col.find({"aaaa":1})
>>> cur2 = col.find({"bbbb":2})

>>> data = [x for x in chain(cur1, cur2)]
>>> data
[{u'aaaa': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('51f6a2ef0fef4e0daccc50e1')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('51f6a2fb0fef4e0daccc50e2'), u'bbbb': 2}]
```

Comment: I should have specified that I need the object to stay as a Cursor, but that is the case.

Comment: It is not. It's `<class 'list'>`